# Copying one row of dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have two dataframes, say df1 and df2.

```
df1[Age]: 10, 20 30

df2[Income]: 100, 1000, 1500
```

How do I create a new dataframe df3 which consists of rows from df1 such that

```
df2.loc[k]['income'] >1000?
```

In the example given above, I would have

```
df3[Age]: 20, 30
```

Similarly, `df4[Age, Income]: (20, 1000), (30, 1500)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [232]: df3 = df1.join(df2).query("Income >= 1000")

In [233]: df3
Out[233]:
   Age  Income
1   20    1000
2   30    1500
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [269]: idx = df2.index[df2.Income.ge(1000)]

In [270]: df3 = df1.loc[idx].join(df2.loc[idx])

In [271]: df3
Out[271]:
   Age  Income
1   20    1000
2   30    1500
```

or simply:

```
In [275]: df2.loc[df2.Income.ge(1000)].join(df1)
Out[275]:
   Income  Age
1    1000   20
2    1500   30
```

Comment: Thank you. What if df2 is large and contains a lot of irrelevant data, then the join(df2) step would take a time and in the end most of the irrelevant data will be discarded. Any thoughts on this?